# Change text color on ng-binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I want to change the color of the text, if Pending it should bind class text-success and if On Time it should bind class text-danger, however its not working..

```
<tr ng-repeat="entries in abc" ng-click="/#/mypage/{{entries._id}}">
                            <td>{{$index}} </td>
                            <td>{{entries.objective}}</td>
                            <td>{{entries.key_results[0].result}}</td>
                            <td ng-class="{text-success: entries.key_results[0].status == 'Pending', text-danger: entries.key_results[0].status == 'On Time' }">
                            {{entries.key_results[0].status}}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{entries.final_score}}</td>
                            <td>{{entries.owner_ids[0]}}</td>
                            <td> <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success"> View OKR </a></td>
                        </tr>
```

Other data are getting displayed perfectly ..
Controller :

```
$scope.abc = [
          {
            "_id": "560b84bc1bf86c4334dd7233",
        "objective": "My obj",
        ....
            "key_results": [{
                "result": "res1",
                "current_score":0.6,
                "final_score":0.7,
                "status":"Pending"
            },
            {
                "result": "res2",
                "current_score":0.6,
                "final_score":0.7,
                "status":"Pending"
            }]
          },
          {
         "_id": "560b84bc1bf86c4334dd7233",
        "objective": "My obj 2",
        ....
            "key_results": [{
                "result": "res1",
                "current_score":0.6,
                "final_score":0.7,
                "status":"On time",
                "_id": "560bb0a70aea6b067d961653"
            },
            {
                "result": "res2",
                "current_score":0.6,
                "final_score":0.7,
                "status":"On time",
                "_id": "560bb0a70aea6b067d961652"
            }]
          }
    ]
```

I took ref from: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/NHS73/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you your `ng-class` has two words separated by dash `-` for example
`text-success` then you need pass this as a string like `"text-success"` if the class name is just a word without dash (`-`) then you can use as u do in this question.

**WHY**

check the argument pass to `ng-class`

`{text-success: entries.key_results[0].status == 'Pending', text-danger: entries.key_results[0].status == 'On Time' }`

this is a `json` object, in `json` object you have key value pairs,

here the first key is `text-success` & value is equals to `entries.key_results[0].status == 'Pending'` which is `true` or `false`.

the second key is `text-danger` & value is equals to `entries.key_results[0].status == 'On Time'` which is `true` or `false`.

So if the `json` object have a keys like `text-success` then they should be quoted as `"text-success"` that's the way we deal with `json`.

**SOLUTION**

enclose the css classes passed to `ng-class` with `double` or `single` quotes, if the css class is just a word without `-` separated then don't need the quotes, But if you like to quote the single word classes it's also ok. *(think the argument pass to `ng-class` as a json that's all)*.

```
<td ng-class="{'text-success': entries.key_results[0].status == 'Pending', 'text-danger': entries.key_results[0].status == 'On Time' }">
```

Comment: :) glad to help you, cheerz

Answer (score 1):

you are missing quotation marks around the class names.  it should look like this:

```
<td ng-class="{'text-success': entries.key_results[0].status == 'Pending', 'text-danger': entries.key_results[0].status == 'On Time' }">
```

JSFiddle with [working styling](https://jsfiddle.net/nyL8nLok/)

Comment: @atjoshi updated answer with correct fix & a working jsfiddle